# Convexity of $x\mapsto \mathrm{tr}(e^{-E\langle a,x\rangle}bb')$

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, trace

Let $E$ be a matrix with entries equal to one minus the identity matrix and $a,b$ known vectors. Is the function $$x\mapsto \mathrm{tr}(e^{-E\langle a,x\rangle}bb')$$

convex?

Comment: Please express more clearly what are the unknowns in the problem.

Comment: What does the expression $-E\langle a,x\rangle$ mean? Is it a scalar multiplication of the matrix $E$ by the scalar $-\langle a,x\rangle$?

Comment: Yes, $\langle a,x\rangle = a'x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is convex. Since $E$ admits an orthogonal diagonalisation $Q\operatorname{diag}(n-1,\,-1,\ldots,-1)Q^T$, if we put $c=Q^Tb$, the function in question can be rewritten as
$$
x\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^n|c_i|^2\exp(-\lambda_i\langle a,x\rangle),
$$
where $\lambda_1=n-1$ and $\lambda_2=\cdots=\lambda_n=-1$. This is a non-negatively weighted sum of convex functions. Hence it is convex.

Comment: Thank you, this looks great. Obviously, if we had $x\mapsto \mathrm{tr}(e^{-A-E\langle 
 a,x\rangle}bb')$, then this would not work unless $A$ had the same eigenvectors as $E$, right?

Comment: @Lionville If $A$ does not commute with $E$, the analogous argument in my answer will not work, but that doesn't mean the function must be non-convex (I think it is still convex, but I am not sure).