# Convexity of $t\mapsto b'e^{-A-Bt}b$

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $b$ be some given vector and $A,B$ arbitrary symmetric matrices, and $A$ is positive definite. Is the function $$t\mapsto b'e^{-A-Bt}b$$ convex?

This is related to another question:
[Convexity of $x\mapsto \mathrm{tr}(e^{-E\langle a,x\rangle}bb')$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3326421/convexity-of-x-mapsto-mathrmtre-e-langle-a-x-ranglebb?rq=1)

Comment: I think this boils down to asking whether the matrix exponential is convex w.r.t to the Löwner order, i.e. if $X$ and $Y$ are symmetric, do we have $\exp(\lambda X+(1-\lambda) Y) \preccurlyeq \lambda \exp(X) + (1-\lambda) \exp(Y)$ ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems that the exponential is not operator convex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $AB=BA$, then the function is convex; otherwise, it's false. See, for example

$b=[45,-14]^T,A=\begin{pmatrix}13.84&5.64\\5.64&2.44\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}-0.26&-0.63\\-0.63&-0.23\end{pmatrix}$ on $t\in [5,15]$.

Comment: Your counterexample is great, thank you! Is there an idea behind it. I tried to come up with a numerical counterexample but was always getting convexity.

Comment: +1 I had trouble to obtain a numerical counterexample too.